# I want an opto-isolated MOSFET driver that works at high frequency

Tags: mosfet, frequency

Is there an opto-isolated MOSFET driver that works at high frequency?

If possible show the circuit.

It's for ballast, fluorescent lamps, and things like this. I'm really a layman about these things. but it's not for me, so I asked for help. The frequency is in the range of kilohertz, average 25 I guess...

Comment: Please define "high frequency".

Comment: I think you'll find that you'll need to give a bit more information than that.

Comment: Why does it need opto isolation. There are other ways of skinning a cat.

Comment: 25KHz is not what most people consider high frequency. That is common or even on the low side of most switching frequencies used now days. Just about any opto-isolator should work for this depending on how fast of edges and how hard of a drive you need.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency is easy enough. I use opto isolators for [IGBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated-gate_bipolar_transistor) driving up to 15 kHz (limited by powercore losses, not by the opto isolator).

- ACPL-312T if you want direct FET/IGBT driving
- ACPL-M61T for an open-collector output